# Splitting a part of the file name and transform it into data in R

Tags: r, file, date, filenames, dataformat

I have some files in the following format `data_25_05_2018.csv` which have 4 columns with 30 values each.

I would like to add a column with the same date for each one of them, so the idea would be to tell R to take the name of the file, split it and just take the part `25_05_18` and the transform it into a valid date format and create a column.

Is there a form to transform a part of a file name into data in R?

Comment: You can use `strptime` to convert a string to a date as such: `strptime("data_25_05_2018.csv", format = "data_%d_%m_%Y.csv")`

Comment: Expanding on Bas' comment, you could also use `as.Date` in the same vein: `as.Date("data_25_05_2018.csv", format = "data_%d_%m_%Y.csv")`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression and the `dmy()` function from `lubridate` to do this:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tibble)
## make some fake data
DF <- matrix(rnorm(120), ncol=4)
colnames(DF) <- c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4")
##  turn data into a tibble 
DF <- as_tibble(DF)
## make file name
x <-  "data_25_05_2018.csv" 
## extract everything between data_ and .csv
x <- gsub("data_(.*)\\.csv", "\\1", x)
## use dmy to turnit into a date and add to data frame
DF$date <- dmy(x)

> head(DF)
# # A tibble: 6 x 5
# V1     V2     V3     V4 date      
# <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <date>    
#   1  0.692    -1.51   1.74  -0.585 2018-05-25
# 2  1.08     -0.812 -1.55  -1.98  2018-05-25
# 3  0.000229  2.55  -0.577 -0.619 2018-05-25
# 4  0.940    -0.906  0.990 -1.48  2018-05-25
# 5 -1.78      0.815  0.436 -0.125 2018-05-25
# 6 -0.324     0.735  0.974  0.151 2018-05-25
```